# SQL Previous Record Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have following table:

```
+---------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
|TravLotID|TravLineNum|ProjectCycleTime|    CapacityValue    |
+---------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
|  14405  |    1      |     60         | 2011-03-16 16:00:00 |  
|  14405  |    2      |     90         |                     |
+---------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
```

I want to add a new field called `FordwardSchdDate`.
For the first row it should add `ProjectCycleTime` value to `CapacityValue`. And then cumulative results.

For example here's what result should be:

```
+---------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|TravLotID|TravLineNum|ProjectCycleTime|   CapacityValue     | FordwardSchdDate    |
+---------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  14405  |      1    |      60        | 2011-03-16 16:00:00 | 2011-03-16 17:00:00 |  
|  14405  |      2    |      90        |                     | 2011-03-16 18:30:00 |
+---------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I need help thinking of a logic on how this can be accomplished. Here's what I have so far

```
( CASE WHEN TravLineNum = 1
   THEN dbo.fn_DateAdjustWorkingDaysOnly(0 - wt.ProjectedCycleTime, wt.CapacitySlotDateTimeValue)
   ELSE  ' '--dbo.fn_DateAdjustWorkingDaysOnly (wt.ProjectedCycleTime + wt.ParentMinutes, wt.SchdDate)
   END ) AS ForwardSchdDate,
```

Is there any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hello, I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Look up lag/lead and dateadd

Comment: I tried the date add but its not calculating correctly. I used

dateadd(minute, SUM(wt.ProjectedCycleTime) OVER(Partition by wt.TravLineNum), wt.CapacitySlotDateTimeValue) AS ForwardSchdDate,